# Как обновить NULL / 0 в mysql (редактирование страницы)?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

в общем такая ситуация. Вызываю на редактирование страницу из базы, загружаются для редактирования все поля по (describe), в поля которые заполнены помещаются значения по умолчанию которые есть в базе, в поля у которых нет значений открываются пустыми, вот пример вывода этих полей:

```
if ($colums[$key] == 'partner_id') {
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='partner_id'>";
    echo "<option value=''>выбрать партнера</option>";        
    $partner  = DBselect('id,name,email','users','access','partner',false);
    foreach ($partner as $rows) {
        if ($service['partner_id'] == $rows['id']) {
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='{$rows['id']}'>{$rows['name']} / {$rows['email']}</option>";
            continue;
        }
    echo "<option value='{$rows['id']}'>{$rows['name']} / {$rows['email']}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></br>"; 
    }
    if ($colums[$key] == 'partner_bonus') {
    echo "<input class='form-control' value='{$service['partner_bonus']}' type='number' name='{$colums[$key]}' placeholder='Менеджерский процент'><br>";
    }
```

Я хочу избавится от обязательства заполнения всех полей, например хочу отредактировать, только 1 значение и сохранить, и возникает проблема, что на всех полях где не заполненно выходит ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
>   format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '' for column
>   `arenda_db`.`service`.`data_end` at row 1 in

Понятно, я пытаюсь передать пустое значение, и он ругается. При создании поля (ИНСЕРТЕ) я чищу массив, и те поля которые не указаны просто удаляю, и таким образом записываю только заполненные поля. С помощью вот такой функции (только не хахочите слишком громко):

```
function cleandata($_data):array {
    foreach ($_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($_data[$key]) {
            $return_data[$key] = $value; 
        }
    }
    return $return_data;
}
```

Потом отдаю в ИНСЕРТ, и он записывает все поля. Однако, на обновление информации я ее использовать не могу, так как бывают случаи когда нужно не отредактировать информацию в записи, а удалить и установить значение NULL в базе, и в таком случае эта функция перед обновление убирает это значение из обновления.

Я пробывал в значению по умолчанию на select ставить типа:

```
<option value='NULL'>выбрать партнера</option>";
```

Это не как не помогло, кроме того. Выручает если везде проставлять по умолчанию значение "0", но во первых это треш, а во вторых поля типа:

```
echo "<input value='{$service['data_end']}' class='form-control' type='date' name='{$colums[$key]}'></br>";
```

Ругаются, на ноль тоже.

Прошу  подсказать в каком направлении действовать, что бы создать свободную форму обновления, которая может и удалить значение, установив в базе NULL, а так же обновлять только частичную информацию спасибо. Заранее спасибо, извините если вопрос глупый.

Мои обновлятор базы:

```
function DBupdadeAll($_table, array $_data_update,$_where_name): bool
{
    global $pdo;
    $_data_str_update = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_data_update as $key => $value) {
        //echo "$key";
        //echo "$value";
        if($i != count($_data_update)-1){
        $x = "`$key` =:$key, ";
        $_data_str_update.=$x; 
       }
       else{
        $x = "`$key` =:$key ";
        $_data_str_update.=$x; ; 
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE {$_table} SET $_data_str_update WHERE `$_where_name`=:$_where_name");
    if (!$sql) {
         echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
         print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
     }
    $sql->execute($_data_update);
    echo 'Запись обновлена';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: А вы поля не удаляйте, а заменяйте их на NULL. Правда со строками могут возникнуть проблемы, там вы никогда не можете отличить пустую строку от null при приходе из браузера. Так что возможно надо заменять на null только критичные к этому поля: числовые и даты

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, в функцию cleandata (код выше) сделать обратную проверку, и к ключам у которых нет значения присвоить NULL, примерно вот так: $return_data[$key] = 'NULL';

Comment: Только NULL не в кавычках, а то получите строку с 4 буквами NULL

Comment: Надеюсь вы запрос к БД собираете с bind_param, а не подставляете значения в текст ...

Comment: Без него, опубликую свою функцию обновления в тело вопроса. везде в примерах без bind_param показывают. Я так понимаю bind_param присвоет к значениям типа  int, str, и другое, и тогда NULL станет не текстом, а значением.?

Comment: Ну тогда установка null в массиве вам ничего не даст. Потому как `insert into table(date) value(NULL)` и `value('NULL')` совершенно разные вещи. А вот bind_param (или более удобная передача в массиве execute, при использовании pdo) сама разберется и сделает все правильно

Answer (score 1):

Пустые строчки в input - value='' перед добавлением в базу данных, нужно проверить и заменить на значение NULL, для этого в функцию DBupdadeAll добавления добавил код:

```
foreach ($_data_update as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($_data_update[$key])) {
                $_data_update[$key] = NULL;
            }
        }
```

После этого все разработало. Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) что помог разобраться.